# How can I change relative size of panel?

Tags: c#, size, panel, android-relativelayout

I have 2 panels in a mother panel. The idea is smallest panel docked at bottom pushes 2nd panel inside the motherpanel to the top when up arrow is selected and displays the length it is going. What I want to do is as the panels stay at the same height, the length grows  and the bottom dock panel moves slower. Change the relative sizing I guess?

Comment: Could you explain more clear, I could not understand what you want to do exactly.

Comment: ok think of a panel its height is 10 cm but ı want it to be seem as 50 so when ı move the panel at the bottom towards up it pushes it longer but ı cant make the 10cm panel longer cause there are panels on top of it for other controls. ı think it is more clear now.

Comment: you have 2 panels in a mother panel?
what is these 2 panel dock properties set to? (Assume the bottom panel is A and upper one is B)

Comment: both docked to bottom ,  small panel at bottom pushes the panel on top of it . There are 2 of this system but ı want them stay at the same length but as one goes 10 cm the other one goes 1 cm. I think it might have something to do with pixel size or am ı wrong?

Comment: Could you please demonstrate some picture of this problem, i really could not imagine the situation.